# Capture Parameters from Swagger File

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml, swagger, openapi

Are there any node modules to capture the parameters and paths from a Swagger File?

I have tried js-yaml which converts YAML to JSON but while working on the Petstore swagger  ( https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json ) if there is a reference to a variable  the reference is shown but the actual values have to be captured through the reference variable.(for e.g. in the definitions for 'Pet' the 'category' variable is defined. However the values are defined in another definition named Category)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve - just parse the spec, or something else (e.g. send requests to the endpoint in the spec, generate sample JSON/XML from model definitions, ...)?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to read a Swagger file and extract details from it such as the API Name, description, request and response parameters if any.